# Why the VueJS store is not updated for some users?

Tags: ios, vue.js, vuejs2, safari, vuex

Im having a project in VueJS 2.6.12.
I have a store with VueX and if I modify the code, I still see the old code version using Safari on IOS. The code is probably cached but why is not updated with the new code?

On my computer using Chrome, I dont see this problem.

How can to make sur that the user will always use the latest version deployed?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have dev tools opened in Chrome? Then that's likely the difference, not Google vs Apple. This shouldn't have to do anything with Vue. This is specific to the way the project is built (asset files should have hashes) and the server (index file should have respective cache headers so it's not cached after being updated).